# Neo4j how to create/delete relationships from a set of nodes ids

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a `User` nodes and `Intersets` node. I want to be able given an array of interests to create/delete/change the relationship between the `User` and the `Interests` I also want in the same query to update some properties on the user node.

So far this is what i have menage to do:

```
MATCH (user:User {id: id})
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[oldRel:InterestedIn]->(:Interest)
DETACH DELETE oldRel
WITH user
UNWIND {interestsIds} as id
MATCH (interest:Interest {id: id})
MERGE (user)-[rel: InterestedIn]->(interest)
SET user.name = {user}.name, ..(more sets)
RETURN user, collect(interest) as interests
```

I think this one is working tho some time is looks like the `interests` are returned duplicated..
As well this query looks like a bit of an overkill. Any idea how to do that query with a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this seem about right?

```
MATCH (user:User {id: id})
OPTIONAL MATCH (interest:Interest)
WHERE interest.id IN {interestsIds}
MERGE (user)-[:InterestedIn]->(interest)

WITH DISTINCT user
MATCH (user)-[rel:InterestedIn]->(interest:Interest)
WHERE NOT(interest.id IN {interestsIds})
DELETE rel

WITH DISTINCT user
MATCH (user)-[:InterestedIn]->(interest:Interest)
RETURN user, collect(interest)
```

Comment: How can i return the all the new interests from that query?

Comment: Also when sending an empty `{interestsIds}` nothing seems to happen i get empty results

Comment: I just made an edit to take care of the empty `{interestsIds}` case.  I'm not quite sure how to return the new interests.  Do you mean only the ones that were created, or do you mean all of the interests that are attached to the user after the query is done?

Comment: I want to be able to return the user and collect all the interesets that he is now connected to..

Comment: I just added a bit which should give you that.  It's not really shorter than your query, but it might be a bit more straightforward

Comment: Isnt that better in this case just to use batch query?

Comment: Good question...  I'd benchmark it and see.  Some Neo4j library might not make it easy to do batch queries (I'm a maintainer of one such library, but that's something I hope to fix), so sometimes it's easier to just make it all part of one query

Comment: Last question.. Asumming im useing batch.. Can i count on the results order? Fir example if we take the above query and split it to 3? The last part will always be the result after the new relationships?

Comment: Yeah, I'm 99.9% sure that the order of statements that you give to the batch endpoint will be the order that the queries would run in.